# takes too much time to upload build on app store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm updating a new version of app in app store through `XCode` and I am creating build like below

> Step 1. Project Setting -> General Signing -> Automatically Manage
>   Sign in
>
> Step 2. Select Generic iOS Device
>
> Step 3. Product -> Archive -> Build

After creating build i'm uploading build on app store through `XCode` Organizer but its take to much time to upload and message show as below

**Authenticating With the app store...**

Here is the image I am attaching

[image: Please Check Screen Shot]

please check image I'm stuck from last 2 3 hours i'm just getting this message

Comment: Use `Application Loader` to push .ipa file into  `itunes connect`

Comment: will you please guide me how to use application loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your network you use to build? I stuck same process when use company's network because VPN. Try to use another network

Comment: i our organisation we don't use VPN still i am getting this problem

Comment: I mean something in network make it not work. Could you try your cellular network or different network from your company to upload it?

Comment: Thanks You are right i tried with cellular network and its work for me

Comment: Can u approve my ans

Comment: Export app as Ipa file and upload with transporter (by apple) https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12 Which is 10x faster than xcode upload.

Answer (score 0):

After creating Build go to

```
Distribute App -> iOS App Store -> Export
```

Go to

```
Xcode -> open Developer Tool -> Application Loader
```

Login your apple ID, Select .ipa file and upload to itunes connect.